# Quit Notepad++ when last tab is closed?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to make Notepad++ exit when the last tab is closed, e.g. by pressing `Ctrl+W`?

The current behaviour is that a new empty document is created, when the last open tab is closed.

Comment: When the last tab is closed, use Alt+F4, which is the general shortcut to end programs in windows. Kind regards, mtness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is now available under the preference tab of Notepad++  in the general section.

[image: Image showing where tick mark is.]

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ has a page where you can [request new features](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=95717&atid=612385). Why not ask the author nicely? Who knows you may get the feature built into the next version. The program source code is also available, so if you know a programmer who understands the code and owes you a favour, maybe you could convince them to do it.

Comment: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1006

Comment: Already committed